# Method can't work because methods come before mounted so element doesn't exist

Tags: vue.js

I have a method that refers to a page element.  When I run the same function using the mounted lifecycle, everything works.  However, I want to use the function on a button click.  When I create the method, however, it says the element doesn't exist.

I think I saw that the mounted lifecycle can refer to methods, in which case methods must load first.  How can I "delay" loading of the method just like the mounted lifecycle?

```
<div id="toprint">to be printed</div>
<button v-on:click="print" type="button">print</button>
...
methods: {
        print: printJS({printable:'toprint'})
    }
```

The page is saying "toprint" doesn' exist.  If I were to put printJS into a mounted lifecycle...it will work.

Comment: Are you using `v-on:click`? I'm confused, like are you adding an `onclick` listener within `mounted()`?

Comment: Yes, I'm using v-on-click.  The method calls a function which refers to an ID.  The page says the ID doesn't exist.  However, if I place the same function within mounted (as a test), the ID does exist and the function works properly (so I know the function is working).

Comment: Can you include some code? Hard to help you without it.

Comment: Yes, thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are accidentally calling your `printJS` upon initialization of your component! Wrap that thing in its own function.

```js
methods: {
   print() {
      printJS({ printable: 'toprint' })
   },
}
```